# Grid layout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

Currently, I've got a ListView implementation that looks something like this:

```
{Alert1}
{Alert2}
{Alert3}
{Alert4}
{Alert5}
{Alert6]
{Alert7}
```

xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="4" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Alerts}" 
          HasUnevenRows="True" 
          VerticalOptions="Start"
          SeparatorVisibility="None" Margin="10,0"
          x:Name="AlertsList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="#333333" Margin="0,5" Padding="5">
                    <StackLayout Margin="0" Padding="0">
                        <Label 
                            Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="Large"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Margin="0" />
                        <Label 
                            Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            Margin="0" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Any suggestion on how to modify this so that the output is displayed in a 2 column grid instead with equal width columns such as?

```
{Alert1}{Alert2}
{Alert3}{Alert4}
{Alert5}{Alert6]
{Alert7}
```

I'm using Xamarin Forms v2.3.3

Comment: CollectionView supports this layout.  But you'll need to upgrade - v2.3 is 4 years old

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said,you could upgrade your XF version and use `CollectionView` with its `ItemsLayout` property.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Alerts}"
            ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Frame BackgroundColor="#333333" Margin="0,5" Padding="5">
                <StackLayout Margin="0" Padding="0">
                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Margin="0" />
                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        Margin="0" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
      </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The more you could refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid).

Comment: Thank you though I'm trying to avoid upgrading the version.

Comment: @Bhav Version v2.3.3 is too old,there are a number of new features and controls in the later version.It's better to upgrade if possible.